# Intent causes Fatal Error

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have researched this error here and elsewhere but the causes seem very varied. 
I am new and put together a primitive weather app for practice. Enter a city and state and it goes out to Weatherunderground, pulls an XML feed, parses it and displays a few data points. It was threaded and worked fine. Today I added an Intent to open a new second screen and display the data there. Crash.  Not sure why.  Here is the error log.  I have googled some of the terms in the log also without success.

```
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to   instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.glenngilchrist.weatherapp/com.glenngilchrist.weatherapp.WeatherMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3662)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at com.glenngilchrist.weatherapp.WeatherMainActivity.<init>(WeatherMainActivity.java:31)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  ... 11 more
```

This is some code:

```
 public class WeatherMainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {

        String WunderURL = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/1d4c3256ea6ea9fa/conditions/q/";
        TextView tv;  // text box for retrieved data
        EditText city, state; // data entered by user
        Intent i = new Intent(this, WeatherDetailDisplay.class);

        //StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        Handler handler = new Handler()  {

            @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.results);
        Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
        String string = bundle.getString("myKey");

        if (string.equals("Valid")) {
            // go to detail screen
            String strcity = bundle.getString("myCity");
            String strstate = bundle.getString("myState");
            String strtempF = bundle.getString("myTempF");
            i.putExtra("myCity", strcity);
            i.putExtra("myState", strstate);
            i.putExtra("myTempF", strtempF);
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            tv.setText(string);
        }   
           }
       }; 

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather_main);

            //Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.results);
            city = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.city);
            state = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.state);

            city.setText("Burlington");
            state.setText("VT");

            //StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.weather_main, menu);
    return true;
      }

      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          // run this is a different thread
          Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              // build a URl and go out to the web for data
              String c = city.getText().toString();
              String s = state.getText().toString();

              StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(WunderURL);
              url.append(s+"/"+c+".xml");
              String fullUrl = url.toString();

              Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
              Bundle bundle = new Bundle();


              try{
                  URL weatherURL = new URL(fullUrl);
                  // set up an xmlreader to parse the data
                  SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                  SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                  XMLReader xreader = sp.getXMLReader();
                  // tell the reader to user our handler class
                  XMLHandler xh = new XMLHandler();
                  xreader.setContentHandler(xh);

                  // now open the stream
                  xreader.parse(new InputSource(weatherURL.openStream()));
                  //String text = xh.GetInfoString();
                  String city = xh.getCity();
                  String state = xh.getState();
                  String tempF = xh.getTemp();


                  if (city.contains("null")) {
                      //tv.setText("Invalid Location");
                      bundle.putString("myKey", "Invalid Location");
                      bundle.putString("myCity", "");
                      bundle.putString("myState", "");
                      bundle.putString("myTempF", "");
                      msg.setData(bundle);
                      handler.sendMessage(msg);
                  } else {
                      //tv.setText(text);
                      bundle.putString("myKey", "Valid");
                      bundle.putString("myCity", city);
                      bundle.putString("myState", state);
                      bundle.putString("myTempF", tempF);
                      msg.setData(bundle);
                      handler.sendMessage(msg);
                  }

              } catch (Exception e) {
                  //tv.setText("error");
                  bundle.putString("myKey", "error");
                  bundle.putString("myCity", "");
                  bundle.putString("myState", "");
                  bundle.putString("myTempF", "");
                  msg.setData(bundle);
                  handler.sendMessage(msg);
              }
          }
      };
      Thread mythread = new Thread(runnable);
      mythread.start();
  } 
}
```

Comment: Well, what's the code here: `WeatherMainActivity.java:31`?

Comment: You have a problem at WeatherMainActivity.java:31, but without the code we can't do much about it.

Comment: There is a `null pointer exception` in `WeatherMainActivity.java`. keep a break point in the class and debug through it. You will find the cause of this problem.

Comment: Make sure you have included the activity in your manifest file.

Comment: The code at line 31 mentioned above is startActivity(i) as seen in the above event. It is a nullpointerexception so I assume there is something wrong with the Intent???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to ensure that your new activity is defined in your AndroidManifest.xml file. Minimally, it would be something like this:

```
<activity android:name=".TheNewActivityNameHere"/>
```

Please post code of your main Weather activity for further details.

Comment: You instantiated the intent "i" as a member variable? I would recommend not doing startActivity(i); but instead instantiate the object at runtime in the handleMessage code. (Intent i = new Intent(..); then putExtra(), then startactivity()...)

Comment: OK MiStr - that did it.  Moving the instantiation required changing context from this to getApplicationContext(), and then it ran first time around.

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help. Feel free to accept/vote up my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

WeatherMainActivity.java:31

You're creating an Intent for an activity that's not found by Android.

This is my first impression when seeing your error log.

You may want to go and see what causes the NullPE in **ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)**

This is the most probably a configuration error like MiStr said. I agree with you it would be better to have a clearer error message than an NPE :-)

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3662)
    08-14 14:03:27.314: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at com.glenngilchrist.weatherapp.WeatherMainActivity.<init>(WeatherMainActivity.java:31)
```